# Why doesn't icacls remove a deny ACE

Tags: permissions, icacls

I am trying to discover how to use icacls to remove a specific **DENY ACE**
In my test I deny a special permission like this:

```
icacls mydirectory /deny me:(DC)
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

That works as expected and when I examine the result I see (among other ACEs) this:

```
mydirectory CROMARTY\me:(DENY)(S,DC)
```

Not quite sure why the S (for synchronize) appears, but now I try and remove this denial

```
icacls mydirectory /remove me:(DENY)(DC)
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

which seems to indicate that it didn't process anything at all,
and indeed nothing has changed for the ACL on mydirectory.
I have tried many variations on this eg

```
/remove me:(DC) 
/remove:d me:(DC) ..
```

and none of them work. The only thing that does work is

```
/remove:d me
```

That would, I believe, remove all denials associated with the SID me, not just the one I am targeting

Does icacls have a bug, or am I doing something wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Well to answer my own question.
/remove   removes all the ACE's for . There is no api to remove a specific ACE. That seems like an omission to me.

When instead I run

icacles mydirectory /grant me:(DC)
It removes the deny and, because **me** had previously full permissions the deny disappears and no new grant is created.